# When I use requestReview function of StoreKit, is there any way to know if the user has clicked on Submit or Not Now or Cancel button?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, ios10.3

I am using the `SKStoreKitReviewController` in 10.3 and above to request a rating of the app. The alert is displayed. However, I need to implement a logic, wherein, if the user has already rated the app for one major release then I should not ask the user again for rating. Hence, is there a way to know that the user has successfully submitted the rating? Also, I would want to know if the user clicked on "Not now", so that I can prompt them again for rating after a few days. Is there a way to know this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/), **you cannot prompt a user more than three times in a year**.

> Give users an easy way to provide feedback on the App Store without leaving your app using the SKStoreReviewController API. You can prompt for ratings up to three times in a 365-day period.

Comment: Thanks. 3 occurrences in 365-day period is per major release/version of the app or irrespective of that ?

Comment: The prompt will be shown three times in a 365-day period **irrespecive of version changes**.